# RabbitMq and saving items that pushed to a queue

Tags: database, architecture, transactions, rabbitmq

I have processing scenario:

1. I read data from SQL database
2. I filter the data by processed items table that I read from SQL database as well
3. I push filtered items ids to RabbitMq queue
4. I save pushed items into processed items table in SQL database

And I think we can have problems between step 3 and 4. For example, I pushed data and during saving operation, I didn't save them into DB and It'll cause duplicates.

Can you suggest any scenario to complete this processing?

Comment: this is very unclear. Can you clarify which table you read data from in step 1. Secondly, how/what exactly are you filtering in step 2. Lastly, is the consumer or provider performing step 4?

Comment: We have table with transaction records we read Ids by some filters in 1 step. In second step we read another table "ProcessedItems", this table contains already processed items(Ids) and we filter records that we read in 1 step by data from "ProcessedItems" table. And in step 4 we are saving data by provider.